# How to reference a resource created in one file in another file in terraform

Tags: terraform

`terraform/env/res/main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_all" {
  name        = "allow_all"
  description = "Allow all inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

`terraform/mod/sec/main.tf`:

```
resource aws_elb "elb" { 
  name = "elb-example"
  subnets         = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids}"]
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}"] # SG 
  internal        = false
  listener = [
    {
      instance_port     = "80"
      instance_protocol = "HTTP"
      lb_port           = "80"
      lb_protocol       = "HTTP"
    },
    {
      instance_port     = "8080"
      instance_protocol = "HTTP"
      lb_port           = "8080"
      lb_protocol       = "HTTP"
    },
  ]

  health_check = [
    {
      target              = "HTTP:80/"
      interval            = 30
      healthy_threshold   = 2
      unhealthy_threshold = 2
      timeout             = 5
    },
  ]
  access_logs = [
    {
      bucket = "my-access-logs-bucket"
    },
  ]
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Running into error undefined variable `aws_security_group.allow_all` in variable `aws_security_group.allow_all_id`.

Also, is it possible to verify a string and add an additional security group? Ternary conditional is what I can think of. Can you suggest any other alternatives?

Comment: What does your file look like where you use the data source?

Comment: i am creating a aws_elb resource and accessing this security group in it. resource "aws_elb" "myelb" {  security_groups_1   = [
                        "${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}" ] @yd

Comment: Edit the question to show the entirety of your second file and show the file paths of each of them. If this is a lot of code then you should consider trying to strip this down to a [mcve]

Comment: could you also run `terraform fmt` on your code?

Answer (score 20):

It looks like you have two modules, one is `terraform/mod/sec` and the other is `terraform/env/res`. The former defines an `aws_security_group` resource and the latter uses that security group id to create a `aws_elb` resource.

I'm assuming you're running terraform from the `res` directory which is incorrect. Instead what should be done is output the security group id in the `res` module

```hcl
# env/res/outputs.tf
output "sg_id" {
  value = aws_security_group.allow_all.id
}
```

and then reference the `res` consumable module within the `sec` root dir module.

```hcl
# env/sec/main.tf
module "res" {
  source = "../../env/res"

  # ... additional inputs
}

resource "aws_lb" "default" {
  name            = "lb-example"
  subnets         = [data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids]
  security_groups = [module.res.sg_id] # uses the module output to insert SG
  internal        = false

  listener = [
    # ...
  ]

  # ... additional inputs
}
```

Then this can be run

```
cd terraform/mod/sec
terraform init
terraform plan
```

and that should apply the new security group in the `res` module which outputs the security group id `sg_id`, which is then passed to the `sec` module's resource `aws_lb`'s `security_groups` argument.

Comment: How do I reference the same module in multiple files? It says module names must be unique

Comment: @SouradeepNanda You can have multiple modules with the same source but a different name. For example, the above module in my answer shows `module "sec"` with a source for `env/res`, you can create another module reference with `module "sec2"` with the same source and now you have same module reference with 2 different names.